# How to get static file from nginx via curl?

Tags: curl, nginx

I have this nginx configuration:

```
server {
listen 80;
client_max_body_size 4G;

server_name mysite.ru;

location / {
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_buffering off;
  proxy_pass http://aiohttp;
}

location /static {
  # path for static files
  root /var/www/mysite.ru/public_html;
}
}
```

And i have index.html in /var/www/mysite.ru/public_html. How can i get this file via curl? These doesnt work:

curl -X GET 'http://mysite.ru/static/index.html'

curl -X GET 'http://mysite.ru/index.html'

Comment: Post the output when you curl those addresses? Can you get to http://mysite.ru/static/index.html is a browser?

Answer (score 2):

> curl -X GET 'http://mysite.ru/static/index.html'

With your current configuration, this file will be searched for at `/var/www/mysite.ru/public_html/static/index.html`. Notice that the location is constructed by concatenating the `root` value with the URI. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for more.

---

> curl -X GET 'http://mysite.ru/index.html'

This request will be sent to the upstream `aiohttp` service.

---

If you need to remove the `/static/` path element from the path name, use the `alias` directive:

```
location /static {
    # path for static files
    alias /var/www/mysite.ru/public_html;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for more.